# Magento2 Restrict Store view to a customer group

Tags: magento2, multistore, login, customer-group

I need to restrict 1 storeview to a customer group and require login.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply listen to the event `ControllerActionPredispatch` where you will be checking:

- If the customer is not logged in - redirect the user to the login page with a message
- If the customer is logged in & is of an allowed group -> bypass redirection to login

  OR, you can use this EXTENSION - http://www.magepsycho.com/magento-2-store-restriction-pro.html

Comment: I'm actually using MagePsycho store restriction pro for Magento 1  and trying to see if I can do it myself for our new site. Thanks!